# Why isn't SVG showing by css background-image

Tags: css, svg, background-image

I am able to get an svg to show just fine when I use

```
<img src="../images/jte.svg" alt="Logo">
```

however, when I try and display via css using the following:

html

```
<div class="logo2">
</div>
```

css

```
.logo2 {
background-image: url(jte.svg);
}
```

Nothing is being displayed.  Any idea why this is happening?  I have tried multiple different path options "('../images/jte.svg')  ('jte.svg) no avail though.

Comment: Have you given the DIV dimensions? Empty DIVs don't show up on the page by themselves, unless you define dimensions for them.

Comment: Ok, so giving dimensions does bring up the image.  However, the image is not showing the full thing....

Comment: Check the dimensions of the SVG.

Comment: ah... that's it.  Any recommendations for sizing and exporting in illustrator?

Comment: Why wouldn't css resize svg image according to dimensions?

Comment: The browser uses the size that's specified in the SVG itself, similar to how it treats an ordinary image.  If your container is 100px tall, but your SVG is 200px, only half of it will show.  If you want to resize it, you have to use the `background-size` property:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size

Comment: @user1968859 Background-images don't scale to the element dimensions by default (although there is a method to make it scale, I think).

Answer (score 1):

Use a defined width and height for the element in question, or simply attach it to the body. For example:

```css
body { background-image: url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg')
```